# Running storyboard animations in windows 8 datatemplate

Tags: windows, xaml, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I'm trying to create a to do list in Windows 8 XAML.  when I complete an item, I want a storyboard to erase the completed items.  How can I get a storyboard to run on items inside a datatemplate?  when I run the storyboard from C#, I get an error that says: WinRT information: Cannot resolve TargetName rectangleToDelete.

My storyboard looks like this:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Name="AnimateDelete">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.ScaleX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangleToDelete">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="-0.333"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="-327.5"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.TranslateX)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangleToDelete">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.333"/>
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1.5" Value="-163.25"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</Page.Resources>
```

My Listview template looks like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>

    <Grid>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                  Margin="0,0,-393,-15">
        <CheckBox x:Name="CheckBoxComplete"
                  IsChecked="{Binding Complete, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Checked="CheckBoxComplete_Checked"
                  Content="{Binding Text}"
                  Margin="10,5"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  MinWidth="300" />
        <Button x:Name="ButtonDelete"
                Click="ButtonDelete_Click"
                Content="Delete" />
      </StackPanel>
      <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle"
                 Fill="#FFF4F4F5"
                 Stroke="Black"
                 StrokeThickness="0"
                 RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                 Margin="319,2,-300,-14"
                 Height="34"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
          <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1" />
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
      </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
  </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

My codebehind looks like this:

```
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        TodoItem item = btn.DataContext as TodoItem;

        StackPanel stk = (StackPanel)btn.Parent;
        Grid grd = (Grid)stk.Parent;
        Rectangle rect = (Rectangle)grd.Children[1];
        rect.Name = "rectangleToDelete";
        AnimateDelete.Begin();
```

as you can see, I've tried finding the rectangle and giving it the correct name, but I get the same error.

any help would be appreciated!

thanks, tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DataTemplate has a different namescope than anything outside. You can put the contents of that DataTemplate and the Storyboard in their own UserControl to get it to work.